# logic behind the code

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

could any one explain me logic behind this code??

```
   pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
   pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
   pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
   pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
```

Comment: If you format your code as code we will be better able to help you.  Figure out what the little icons above the text box on the question and answer pages are for, they will enrich your life on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You have a point defined by `x0, y0`. You're now creating two other point objects, one at `(-b*1000, a*1000)` and one at `(b*1000, -a*1000)` relative to the original point. Presumably the `1000` is to fix problems of scale, as the values `a` and `b` are on a different scale than the points `x0, y0`.

Comment: hi thanks, its from hough lines opencv code, could you explain me clearly

Comment: they changed it to cartesian and then y they added a*1000, stuff like that,lines for( i = 0; i < MIN(lines->total,100); i++ ) { float* line = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(lines,i); float rho = line[0]; float theta = line[1]; CvPoint pt1, pt2; double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta); double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho; pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b)); pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a)); pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b)); pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a)); }

Comment: can u help me in loginc behind adding a*1000, after changing to cartesian

Comment: @paddu, there's no way to know why they are multiplying by 1000 just based on this code sample. I'd need more context, and really this is something you'll probably have to figure out for yourself.

Comment: 1000 or other numerical value, its not matter, but after converting polar into cartesian coordinates, which should some x0 = rho * cos(theta), but my question is why they are multiplying 1000*a to rho * cos(theta).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `a` and `b` are threshold values that are being used to move `pt1` in one direction (inwards or outwards) and `pt2` in the opposite direction.

Perhaps they are being used to increase/decrease the area of a rectangle for a bounds check?

Comment: they changed it to cartesian and then y they added a*1000, stuff like that,lines 
       for( i = 0; i < MIN(lines->total,100); i++ )
        {
            float* line = (float*)cvGetSeqElem(lines,i);
            float rho = line[0];
            float theta = line[1];
            CvPoint pt1, pt2;
            double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
            double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
            pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
            pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
            pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
            pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
            
        }